# Traverse an array or cross an array

Tags: php, arrays, echo, traversal

I am fairly new to php and trying to get `echo "<p>" .get_the_tags($author_post). "</p>";` to echo out the tags associated with the post its listing in the loop.

I was told to "you need to traverse the array" and "This returns an array of tags. Then you have to cross the array if you want to echo it out."
but was not told how to accomplish this. I am unsure how to proceed.

Here is the full code.

```
if ($author_posts) {
    echo '<ul>';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($author_posts as $author_post) {
        /* excluded categories   */
        if (has_category(explode(',', $atts['exclude']), $author_post->ID)) :
            continue;
        endif;
        $postdate = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime($author_post->post_date)).' - ';  
        echo '<li>';
        echo ($atts['postdate'] ? $postdate : ''). '<a href="' . get_permalink( $author_post->ID ) . '">'.$author_post->post_title.'</a>';
        $categories = get_the_category( $author_post->ID );
        $list_cats =null;
        foreach ($categories as $cat) :
            $list_cats .= $cat->name.", ";
        endforeach;
        $list_cats = substr($list_cats, 0, -2);
        echo "<p>" .get_the_tags($author_post). "</p>";
        echo '</li>';
        $i++;
        if ($atts['postsperauthor'] > -1) :
            if ($i >= $atts['postsperauthor']) :
                break;
            endif;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `get_the_tags()` return an `array`

try this:

```
$tags = get_the_tags($author_post);
$tagNames = [];
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tagNames[] = $tag->name
}
echo implode(',',$tagNames)
echo '</div>';

echo '</li>';
```

BTW , this syntax is a bit old...

Comment: After more digging and hitting my head I was able to come up with
`$tags = get_the_tags($author_post);
                echo '<div class="righttext">- Tags: ';
                foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
                    echo $tag->name. ', ';
                }
                echo '</div>';`

That did what I needed, somewhat, because now there is an extra (comma) at the end of the list?